# Enabling "entity translation" disables term translation in Drupal (name and description)

Tags: i18n-l10n

i want to translate taxonomy terms and their description text. 
When I enable the module "entity-translation" and check "Taxnomie-terms" in admin/config/regional/entity_translation, the terms and descriptions get synchronized. Means: If I enter the German termname and description and switch to english and change it there, it also changes on the german translation.

The lables show:

- Name (all languages)
- Description (all languages)

And I don't know how to change that. Ideas for solving my problem welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Ad documented on the [Entity Translation project page](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation): "[Title](http://drupal.org/project/title) module allows to replace entity labels with fields to make them translatable." With the Title module you are able to replace the non-Field title and description properties taxonomy terms with Fields translatable with Entity Translation.

Comment: Awesome, I never would have guessed that the Title module supports the description property too.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, after hours of frustrating research we found the solution.

- please check if you have "title" module installed.
- then go to /admin/structure/taxonomy/[vocabulary_name]/fields
- for title and description hit "replace"

Answer (score 0):

Hours??? In my case it has been days!!! And I'm desperate (again!)

If Drupal is already counter intuitive by itself in general and even more for translations, taxonomy always has been a hundred times worse.

However, I did achieve a certain (not full) level of taxonomy translation through field (or entity) translation doing something like:

1. for the vocabulary ("Special") I went to: "Localize" under admin/structure/taxonomy/special/edit
   Save&Translate -> NL:"Speciaal", IT:"Speciale", ES:"Especial"
2. for the term ("To be developed") I went to: nl/taxonomy/term/85/edit/nl or was it taxonomy/term/85/translate?? (this for each language). 
   On both pages it says I have this URL alias for each language, but when I use that path (eg /nl/speciaal/te-ontwikkelen) I get a "Page not found" error. 
   Same goes for /it/speciale/da-sviluppare, /es/especial/por-desarrollar
   Only Generic (Drupal's "Default") works: special/to-be-developed

Also the translated Terms of "to-be-developed" do not appear as options in the translated version of the "Special" Vocabulary when editing content.
HOW does Taxonomy get to understand that both Vocabulary and Term already exist, have been translated and that these paths should work????

3. also did translation under admin/config/regional/translate/edit/9709?destination=admin/config/regional/translate/translate

What should be the next step should to get also the other languages to work (without creating additional term IDs)?

Additionally my hope was to have Taxonomy terms syncronized EVEN with entity translation (new translation of content -> tax term already selected) as is possible with menu items to have just one instance in the list.
Is this actually possible?

Also I have not been able to find the "language is in" option for the "Special" vocabulary in Views: admin/structure/views/view/special
How can I get that?

And last but not least: path is not translated either they all go to /lang/special even if "Special" already has been translated to the other languages in all possible places (although you never know)

BTW one should definitely should NOT FORGET to also activate the field-translation options for Taxonomy (Vocabulary and/or terms) in several other places, before Drupal or Taxonomy even understand you really MEAN to use entity (or field?) translation all over the site (not just in only one expceptional place) and the above can even occur. Unfortunately after days of going through the impossible Drupal-Taxonomy-FieldTranslations labyrinth, I do not remember all the steps, nor the order I have taken, nor which of these steps were actually valid.
Anyway several of these places, randomly (don't know if all) are:
- admin/structure/taxonomy/special/fields/name_field
- to keep up common sense, indeed also in the Title module: admin/config/content/title
- in the content type: admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/fields/field_category
- of course several additional things under the translation interface admin/config/regional/translate/translate
not forgetting string refreshment admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string
- and I don't remember if somewhere else in Drupal's translation labyrinth (specifically having to activate entity (or field?) translations for taxonomy or vocabulary or terms...) Maybe some module configuration or special permissions...

Example at: http://europinion.is/special/to-be-developed (if it doesn't break of course) you can see:
1 - the Vocabulary menu item is translated, however linking to non translated path
2 - Term also appears, however linking to a path that gives error
3 - vocabulary/term reference appears translated in the content with "page not found" path again

Answer (score 0):

The entity translation approach for taxonomy term can be a bit of a mess indeed.

I had created my vocabulary and terms before I enabled "**Field translation. Term fields will be translated through the Entity translation module.**" in my vocabulary settings (admin/structure/taxonomy/(*yourvocabulary*/edit).

As a result Views wouldn't properly output the translated term name and description (it would stick with the source translation).

**Solution:**

*Notice: the steps below are advised when enabling "Field translation", replacing the title and description field and re-saving each term isn't working out.*

1. I deleted and recreated the vocabulary from scratch,
2. enabled Entity translation on it first of all this time (note: it may [require a patch to obtain this *Field translation*](https://www.drupal.org/node/1661348) option, and running `update.php` may be required right after that),

[image]

3. replaced both the title and description fields with entity fields (using the Title module),
4. and finally added the terms again.
5. Once the terms and their descriptions where all there in the source
   language, I translated them one by one.

Mind you that it's possible that there's no "translate" link directly next to the term in the overview. To translate the term, click its "edit" link, and then you'll find "translate" tab.

This time Views would properly render the translated output of both the term name and description.

-> On a sidenote: taxonomy fields may be more practical than select option fields in content types, especially when it comes to URL patterns and their translation.
-> When you accidentally enabled taxonomy translation and attempted to translate a term, and now the Entity Translation approach has no longer effect: go to the database and find the table `entity translation`. Find the term (by its TID), and assign a language to it in the `language` column (instead of `und`). In case it's still not working: also provide this language in the `language source` colum. Now the translate tab to appear again on the term's edit page.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (beta6) of entity translate now supports Taxonomy term translation